# Django "fields" attribute of user forms (UserCreationForm and UserChangeForm)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, field, django-users

According to [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use):

> It is strongly recommended that you explicitly set all fields that should be edited in the form using the fields attribute.

I have a custom user model, so I overrode `UserCreationForm` and `UserChangeForm`, but I'm not sure about the `fields` attribute of the Meta class.
The admin site will be editing all fields of a user; so in `UserChangeForm`, do I have to include all fields in this attribute? like this:

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = (
        "email",
        "password",
        "is_active",
        "is_staff",
        "is_superuser",
        "date_joined",
        "last_login",
        "groups",
        "user_permissions",
        # maybe there are others that I'm missing?
    )
```

Or in this case, it's safe to use the `'__all__'` shortcut?

The admin site uses `UserChangeForm` for editing user attributes (including permissions and so); so these need to be included in the `fields` attribute. But does this mean using the `UserChangeForm` anywhere other than the admin site, causes those security issues mentioned in the docs?

Comment: I'm not quite understand your issue. Are you saying you don't want to include `__all__` or ?

Comment: @Raja No, I'm asking is it okay to do so? because the docs say I shouldn't use `__all__`.

Comment: Hello @aaronn while creating form for normal user if you pass `__all__` in fields this means you're allowing normal user to become superuser or any type of user by editing form or creating. That is why django recomend to specify fields while creating or editing user's data.

Comment: In some tutorials, I've seen that they only include the 'email' field. but I thought all fields that are going to be edited should be included.

Comment: @Ankit Yes this is exactly what I'm worried about. But in the admin site I'm going to need to edit the "is_superuser" attribute or "user_permissions".

Comment: Make sure you give `is_superuser` filed only for superuser you can use django [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Is there a problem with just using `__all__` and then not using `UserChangeForm` anywhere else? I mean, the default UserChangeForm uses it.